# Research Proposal in Statement of purpose for integrated Phd Theoretical Physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, education, quantum-gravity

I wrote this following paragraph in my statement of purpose for my Integrated PhD Physics program in Theoretical physics at best research institute in India.

> **My research proposal in this field is to quantize general relativity by treating spacetime as a clump of binary grains, with few degrees of freedom for field strengths for all fundamental forces, including gravity in form variables defining their orientation. This way of quantization will have an interplay with statistical mechanics to analyze the group behavior of numerous spacetime quanta resulting in tensorial fields such as Electromagnetic Field Strength tensor, the metric tensor and also their higher derivatives such as the Riemann Curvature tensor. This way, the force of gravity will be treated the same as other forces as and we’ll be able to quantize it all together into a single theory.**

Is it a good research proposal or does it look like written by someone who doesn't know what he's talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you will not mind if I am frank: claiming to be able to quantise gravity is silly. Finding a quantum theory of gravity has been an open problem (forgetting about string theory etc. for now) for the best part of a century, so it is extremely unlikely (though of course not strictly speaking impossible!) that you will be able to do so. So unfortunately yes, talking about quantising gravity does make it seem like you don't know what you're talking about.

I am not familiar with the system in India but, in my experience, it is much better to express a general interest in physics and talk about areas that you *might* be interested in, rather than suggesting a particular area of research. You should not be expected to understand research at the cutting edge - the point of a PhD is, after all, to get you to that level of understanding! I would recommend talking about something that you have a firm understanding of, and have enjoyed so far in your studies. I wish you the best of luck with your application :)

Comment: That was super helpful. Thank you very much, sir. Have a lovely day.